# Codeigniter, Passing Inputs of Array and then display the result

Tags: php, codeigniter

Excuse me if this question is already asked everywhere, but i cant find answer that worked.

So I have a dynamically generated table, which is generated by selecting rows from a table in a database.

This is the view file that create the table.

all rows except the heading are created based on how many data found in the table in a database, so, all the inputs are have name like

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="formDtKryw" method="POST" action="updKryw">
<div class="table-responsive form-group row">
    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead class="text-center">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Telepon</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php $no = 0;
    foreach ($dftr_crKryw as $data_crKryw):
        $no_ktp[$no] = $data_crKryw->no_ktp;
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="no_ktp[<?php echo $no; ?>]" id="no_ktp[<?php echo $no; ?>]" value="<?php echo $data_crKryw->no_ktp; ?>">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no+1; ?></td>
                <td><?php   $this->db->select('nama,')->from('dt_prbd')->where('no_ktp', $data_crKryw->no_ktp);
                    $qry = $this->db->get();

                    if ($qry->num_rows() > 0) {
                        foreach($qry->result() as $data):
                            echo $data->nama;
                        endforeach;
                    }
                ?></td>
                <td><?php
                    if ($data_crKryw->memo == NULL) {
                    ?>
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="memo[<?php echo $no; ?>]" id="memo[<?php echo $no; ?>]">
                            <option value="">---Pilih---</option>
                            <option value="Memo 1">Memo 1</option>
                            <option value="Memo 2">Memo 2</option>
                            <option value="Memo 3">Memo 3</option>
                        </select>
                    <?php
                    }
                    else {
                        echo $data_crKryw->memo;
                    }
                ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
        $no++;
            endforeach;
        }
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="totData" id="totData" value="<?php echo $no; ?>">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="11" align="right"><button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan Data</button>  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus Form</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the Controller that should catch the inputs

```
function updKryw(){
    $totData = $this->input->post('totData');

    $no_ktp = $this->input->post('no_ktp');
    $memo = $this->input->post('memo');

    $frmUpdKryw = array(
        'totData' => $totData,
        'no_ktp' => $no_ktp,
        'memo' => $memo
    );

    $this->load->view('display_data', $frmUpdKryw);
}
```

And this is the view file that suppose to view all the captured information from the form

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php

for($x = 0; $x < $totData; $x++){
    echo $totData . "<br>";
    echo $no_ktp[$x] . "<br>";
    echo $memo[$x] . "<br>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

All that displayed is only the $totData, and the $no_ktp[$x] and $memo[$x] is not display anything.

Anyone can help please if there is any error in my code or my logic.

Thanks in advance.

=========================================================================

edit: i started to think that my php engine is broken. why?

even this simple form doesn't display anything.

form.php

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="go.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="firstname">
    <input type="text" name="addr" value="firstaddr">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

go.php

```
$name = $_POST[name];
$addr = $_POST[addr];

echo $name;
echo $addr;
```

Comment: Unclear What you posted and what you asking

Comment: What I ask is how can i catch values from an array of inputs with a same name (ex: input field with name in[0], in[1], and so on) then display it

Comment: what are the values pass to this `$dftr_crKryw` ??

Comment: its a record from a database table, and successfuly acquired because when i query for `nama`, its displayed correctly

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend debug before saving data to $frmUpdKryw array

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter 
$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

Then if data is not empty, before

```
$this->load->view('display_data', $frmUpdKryw);
```

add

```
var_dump($frmUpdKryw);
```

if all is good here, then to debug in beginning of the view

```
var_dump($totData);
var_dump($no_ktp);
var_dump($memo);
```

If all is good here then problem is in your loop, so you will need just fix it. Either you will know where you have problems:

1. failed with sending data with POST
2. failed with saving to new variable
3. failed with sending data to view
4. and last failed with loop

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, will try all suggested above and report the results

Answer (score 0):

when I solve another problem within the same app, this problem is fixed too, the problem is not in the code or logic. all codes are works as expected.

here are the link for the solution. not the solution that I expect, but its working.

[The Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337833/codeigniter-error-with-selecting-data-from-table)

thanks to [Abdulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla) and [Oleg Sapishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2271117/oleg-sapishchuk)