# codeigniter error with selecting data from table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant figure out whats wrong with my model, it said a Fatal Error occured.

Here's my model file:

```
function getName($no_ktp){
    $this->db->select('nama')->from('dt_prbd')->where('no_ktp', $no_ktp);
    $qry_getName = $this->db->get();

    if ($qry_getName->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($qry_getName->result() as $data_getName){
            $hasil_qry_getName[] = $data_getName;
        }
        return $hasil_qry_getName;
    }
}
```

I got this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xampp\[APP_PATH]\M_hrd_apps.php on line 25
```

I thought the error is in the query, so I changed it into this:

```
$qry_getName = 
$this->db->select('nama')
->from('dt_prbd')
->where('no_ktp', $no_ktp)
->get();
```

but the error is the same,

```
Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: echo $no_ktp and make sure it is not null.

Comment: I display it using a view file that i use to test if a var is has a value, and 100% sure that $no_ktp is not NULL

Comment: ok fine so i think you should try to print your query and check by echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: ok or change your this line foreach ($qry_getName->result() as $data_getName){ to foreach ($qry_getName->result_array() as $data_getName){

Comment: the `$this->db->last_query();` return query string, its all good, and when i change `result()` to `result_array()` the error message is still the `num_rows` error

Answer (score 0):

Tr this

```
function getName($no_ktp){
     $this->db->select('nama')->from('dt_prbd')->where('no_ktp', $no_ktp);
      $qry_getName = $this->db->get();
       $result = $qry_getName->result();
       return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives this error. `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean in C:\[APP_PATH]\M_hrd_apps.php on line 25`. Is it right if im thinking that the error is occured because the function that i'm calling is not exist in the codeigniter system?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Model**

```
function getName($no_ktp)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT nama FROM dt_prbd WHERE no_ktp= '$no_ktp'");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count)) 
    {
        $log = 0;
        return $log;
    }
    else
    {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**In controller**

```
$result = $this->Model_name->getName();

if($result == 0)
{
    echo 'Data Is empty';
}
else
{
    $data['name'] = $result;
    #rest of your code
}
```

---

**EDIT 01**

To configure your database

go to `config/database.php` in bottom of page define

1. Databse name
2. Mysql Username
3. Mysql Password

Comment: it returns a number, `1046`, which is an error occured because no database selected. so it means that i dont have a database defined in mysql? and so I check, I have the db, and in the CI config, I have it configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

all problem solved, there is no error in code. i try to re-create the db, and then all script turn out like what i expect.

thanks for all help [Deep Parekh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4960183/deep-parekh) and [Abdulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla)